# is it possible to select an ancestor namespace in typescript

Tags: typescript, nested, namespaces

I generate typescript code that has nested namespaces like this:

```js
namespace A {
        export type MyType = number
}

namespace B {
    const myValue: A.MyType = 6

    namespace A {
    }

}
```

The example doesn't compile because the namespace 'A' inside namespace 'B' hides the namespace 'A' on the root level.
Is there any way that I can access that root level namespace 'A' without altering any of the names of the namespaces?

I tried this (which doesn't work):

```js
namespace A {
        export type MyType = number
}

namespace A_root = A //<--not a valid syntax

namespace B {
    const myValue: A_root.MyType = 6

    namespace A {
    }

}
```

If it cannot be done, I will have to add a suffix to the names of the namespaces (A_0, A_1, etc), but that quite ugly.

Comment: Use an import alias. `import AAlias = A;`

Comment: Looks weird, but it does the trick. If you create an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Aluan Haddad's comment had a suitable answer:

Use an import alias.

```
 import AAlias = A;
```